# Bluetooth volume on headset vs. phone

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, motorola

I have two pairs of Bluetooth headphones (stereo).

With one pair, when I adjust the headphone volume using the buttons on the headphones, it adjusts only the headphone volume and not the phone's Bluetooth audio volume. This is my desired behavior. (My car's (Bluetooth-capable) audio system also displays this behavior - when I adjust the volume in the car, it adjusts only the car's volume, not the phone's.)

With the second pair, when I adjust the volume using the buttons on the headphones, it adjusts *both* the headphone volume *and* the phone's Bluetooth audio volume - making for large steps (large increases and decreases in volume) - too large to be useful.

How can I make the first behavior the default behavior? i.e. make my phone ignore external device's volume commands by default.

Phone is rooted Moto G6 with 8.0 stock

Comment: You can try to change setting 'Disable absolute volume' in Developer options, but it can affect other devices also.

Comment: @hank15 thanks, worked

Comment: @hank15 if u want to repost your comment as an answer, I will accept it